# bash to extract second half of name

Tags: bash, macos, operating-system

Ok so with the new High Sierra, I am trying to write a script to automatically delete there local snapshots that eat up HDD space. I know you can shrink using thinlocalsnapshots / 1000000000 4 but I feel like that is only a band-aid.

So what I am trying to do is extract the date 2018-02-##-###### from:

```
sudo tmutil listlocalsnapshots / 
com.apple.TimeMachine.2018-02-15-170531
com.apple.TimeMachine.2018-02-15-181655
com.apple.TimeMachine.2018-02-15-223352
com.apple.TimeMachine.2018-02-16-000403
com.apple.TimeMachine.2018-02-16-013400
com.apple.TimeMachine.2018-02-16-033621
com.apple.TimeMachine.2018-02-16-063811
com.apple.TimeMachine.2018-02-16-080812
com.apple.TimeMachine.2018-02-16-090939
com.apple.TimeMachine.2018-02-16-100459
com.apple.TimeMachine.2018-02-16-110325
com.apple.TimeMachine.2018-02-16-122954
com.apple.TimeMachine.2018-02-16-141223
com.apple.TimeMachine.2018-02-16-151309
com.apple.TimeMachine.2018-02-16-161040
```

I have tried variations of

```
 | awk '{print $ } (insert number after $)
```

along with

```
 | cut -d ' ' -f 10-.
```

Please if you know what I am missing here I would greatly appreciate it

edit: Here is the script that will get rid of those pesky Local snapshots.If anyone is interested, Thanks again:

```
#! /bin/bash

dates=`tmutil listlocalsnapshots /  | awk -F "." 'NR++1{print $4}'`

for dates in $dates
do
   tmutil deletelocalsnapshots $dates
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close:

```
somecommand | cut -d"." -f4-
# or
somecommand | awk -F"." '{print $4}'
```

You can also try `sed`, but `cut` is made for this.

Comment: Thanks Walter, completely forgot I could add what to separate by!

Answer (score 1):

1- `awk`: you can either specify the field separator with the `-F` option, or print a substring

```
 awk -F. '{print $4}'
 awk '{print substr($0,23)}'
```

2- `cut`: equivalently.

```
 cut -d. -f4
 cut -c23-
```

3- Pure `bash` (sloooooow!): same as above.

```
while IFS=. read s1 s2 s3 d; do echo "$d"; done
while read line; do echo "${line:23}"; done
```

In practice, with a small number of records as in your use case, speed is not an issue and even pure `bash` or regexps (as in other aswers) can be used. As the number of records grows, the higher speed of `awk` and `cut` becomes noticeable.

Answer (score 0):

Using [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) and a [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) :

```
$ grep -oP '\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{6}$'
2018-02-15-170531
2018-02-15-181655
2018-02-15-223352
2018-02-16-000403
2018-02-16-013400
2018-02-16-033621
2018-02-16-063811
2018-02-16-080812
2018-02-16-090939
2018-02-16-100459
2018-02-16-110325
2018-02-16-122954
2018-02-16-141223
2018-02-16-151309
2018-02-16-161040
```